# Downloadable files in my application

Tags: android, file, android-fragments

I created a project which uses `Fragments`, and in one of them I want to add some clickable icons that will allow to download a file (one per icon).
I have the files stored on my computer.
I suppose that they have to be copied into my application.

How I can implement this in the code?

[image]

I hope that this picture can explain what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`will allow to download a file` and `they have to be copied into my application` **don't match**: If the files are already on the device (once your app is installed), *what is the sense of downloading those files again*?

Therefore, **either** provide your files inside your app **or** use a file server and download them.

If you decide to provide the files in your app, this will increase the  installation time.
But it would not require an internet connection to download the files again.
So, simply put your files in the `raw` or in the `assets` folder and that's all.
Then simply access your files from that folder.

If the folder isn't already found in your project, simply create it and drop your files in it.